# Find text between Opening parenthesis closing

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to select all the text between Opening parenthesis closing parenthesis.

**Example:**

```
xxxxxxx (Regular Expression) xxxxxxx( One ) xxxxxxx(One Word ) xxxxxxx ( Two Word) 
1) xxxxxxx(lowercase) 
2) xxxxxxx(UPPERCASE)
```

***Result should be:***

1. Match 1: xxxxxxx (Regular Expression)
2. Match 2: xxxxxxx( One )
3. Match 3: xxxxxxx(One Word )
4. Match 4: xxxxxxx ( Two Word)
5. Match 5: xxxxxxx(lowercase)
6. Match 6: xxxxxxx(UPPERCASE)

**Remark :** 
xxxxxxx is any charactor

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A python code that can help.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """xxxxxxx (Regular Expression) xxxxxxx( One ) xxxxxxx(One Word ) xxxxxxx ( Two Word) 
... 1) xxxxxxx(lowercase) 
... 2) xxxxxxx(UPPERCASE)"""
>>> re.findall("([A-Za-z]+ {0,1}\(.*?\))", s, re.MULTILINE)
['xxxxxxx (Regular Expression)', 'xxxxxxx( One )', 'xxxxxxx(One Word )', 'xxxxxxx ( Two Word)', 'xxxxxxx(lowercase)', 'xxxxxxx(UPPERCASE)']
>>>
```

`"([A-Za-z]+ {0,1}\(.*?\))"` is the regex being used.

- `[A-Za-z]+` means one or more occurances of any char in A-Z or a-z
- ` {0,1} means 0 or 1 occurance of space
- `.*` means a character and then zero or more occurrence of chars.
- `?` means a non-greedy way.
- `\(` & `/)` are backslashed as we want to match them too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[^\(\)]*\([^\)]*\)
```

Here is the live demo:

http://regexr.com?300k2

Alternatively if you need to explicitly access the content before parenthesis and the content inside parenthesis use the following regexp which gives names to proper groups:

```
(?<outpar>[^\(\)]*)\((?<inpar>[^\)]*)\)
```

And again this is its live demo:

http://regexr.com?300k5